# How to fix invalid expression error when using a file with an apostrophe in xmlstarlet?

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

When running this bash script;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir="$HOME"/torrents/movies

find "$dir" -type f -name "*.nfo" | 
xargs -d'\n' xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//plot"
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid expression: '/movies/Bliss' (2021)/Blips' (2021).nfo'
runtime error
Evaluating user parameter inputFile failed
no result for /movies/Blips' (2021)/Bliss' (2021).nfo
```

How do you get xmlstarlet to ignore the apostrophe?

Comment: can you show us your directory list

Comment: try `xargs -0`, its the number zero, not letter O

Comment: This might help: https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/bugs/123/ "Status: open"

Comment: @Cyrus Maybe bob_the_bob is a demanding user and is very unsatisfied with the answers we give him.

Comment: xargs -0 doesn't work, I still get the error. If it is in fact a bug then I'm at a dead end.

Comment: That bug is still open, i had this issue too: on windows powershell, I had to give the XML on stdin instead of xmlstarlet reading it itself. Something like `$xml = Get-Content ...` then `echo $xml | xml.exe sel -N ...`,.